# Recognizing "return" key input in Python | Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to figure out how to implement keybindings into my game. By pressing "return", the player should be able to do something.

But I am not able to get my code to recognize when the player presses the return key. My Code is below. I get to the "yay!" part, but "bla" is never written on the commandline, even if I press the "Return" key a thousand times... any ideas on why?

```
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN: # tried it with KEYUP aswell. same result. 
            print "yay!"
            if event.type == K_RETURN: 
               print "bla"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would `event.type` have changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event type attribute does not tell you what key is pressed. The type will always be "KEYDOWN" or "KEYUP" etc.. The actual key that was pressed is stored in the key attribute. From the Pygame documentation:

> The event queue gets pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.KEYUP events when the
>   keyboard buttons are pressed and released. Both events have a key
>   attribute that is a integer id representing every key on the keyboard.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

So perhaps try:

`if event.key == K_RETURN:`

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you! :) that fixed it